# Data doesn't exist in the dictionary in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have created a dictionary in VBA like this:

```
Set Curr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Index = 1 To NoOfCurr
   Curr.Add Cells(15 + Index, 5), Index
Next
```

After creating the dictionary, I would like to check whether a particular string is present in the dictionary. So I have done it this way:

```
tempString = "USD"
itemInarry = IsInArray(tempString, Curr)

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = arr.Exists(stringToBeFound)
End Function
```

But the value of IsInArray is false. Not sure why. Need some guidance on why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get `IsInArray = FALSE` is that you have loaded the Dictionary with `Range` objects as the Keys, and then tested for the existance of a String as a key.

Perhaps you meant `Curr.Add Cells(15 + Index, 5).Value, Index`

(note that with this method if the values in the cells aren't unique you will get an error)